# Prevent div from scrolling over another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div id="header">
  Header
</div>
<div id="leftside">
  Left Side
<!--A lot of text here.-->
</div>
<div id="right-container">
  <div id="one">
    One
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    Two
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

```css
#header {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#leftside {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  width: 39%;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#right-container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 39%;
  padding: 5px;
}
body{height:400px;}
#one {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: white;
  width: 97%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#two{
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  width: 37%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}

#footer {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```
$(document).scroll(function() { 
    var $self = $("#two"); 
    $self.css('margin-top', 0); 
    var twoOffset = $self.offset().top + $self.outerHeight(true); 
    if (twoOffset > ($("#footer").offset().top - 30)) { 
        $self.css('margin-top', -(twoOffset - $("#footer").offset().top)); 
    } else { 
        $self.css('margin-top', '30px'); 
    } 
});
```

See the [JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/fLyrg57t/5/).

The script prevents the div (with `id="two"`) from scrolling over the `footer` div.

But I also want to prevent the div (with `id="two"`) from scrolling over the div (with `id="one"`) directly above it, as you see happening in this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fLyrg57t/6/).

I guess the same script could be used for that, but I have tried to adapt it without succes. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = $('#one').offset().top;   
var x = $('#two').offset().top;   
var y = $('window').scrollTop();  

$(window).scroll(function(){      
    $(this).scrollTop(function(){  
        if (y <= y || x <= i) {
            $('#two').css('position','static');  
        }    
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Mohamed. Where is this placed? Perhaps you can update the JSFIDDLE, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your right container seems messed up.
I would advise you to use http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/ and do

```
$("#two").stick_in_parent();
```

Comment: It remains to be a bit buggy. Only responds properly after I scroll down once first. At first the sticky element goes over it parents edges.  Once scrolled back and tried again, then it works properly.

Comment: Am trying a different approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492032/divs-fixed-and-unfixed-toggle-between-two-absolute-divs