# Divs fixed and unfixed toggle between two absolute divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the following code to make a fixed div ("two") to only remain fixed when scrolling between two absolute positioned divs ("one" and "footer").

But I am having one problem, when the browser window is made smaller or larger the distance between the footer and where the fixed div ("two") becomes unfixed increases or decreases, so that the fixed div becomes unfixed before the footer gets to it or after the footer has passed it.

How can I solve this? Can anyone help?

The [**DEMO here**](https://jsfiddle.net/fLyrg57t/18/).

UPDATE (21 JULY 2016):

It seems that what is happening is:

Because div "leftside" has its width set as a percentage, when the browser window gets dragged smaller the div "leftside" gets higher to fit its content. This leaves div "two" hanging higher above div "footer" because div "two" lowest possible vertical position is set on page load.

I need to maintain the responsive design, and I can't have the page reloading when scaling the browser window because of other functionality in my website. Scaling the page and then refreshing it in the browser actually does reset things properly, but reloading is not an option for me.

Perhaps options to solve this:

1. Is there a way to reset the lowest possible position of div "two"
   when the window is scaled?
2. Or actually even better; perhaps resetting the lowest possible
   position of div "two" very frequently and automatically, or
   everytime the user does something on the webpage or scaling the
   browser window. This because I have collapsible segments in the div
   "leftside" that will make this div higher or less high without even
   scaling the  browser window.

I guess adaptation needs to be made in this section of the code(?):

```
$window.resize(function()
    {
        bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};
```

Here the full script:

```
var window = this;

$.fn.followTo = function (from, bumper) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(window),
        $from = $(from),
        $bumper = $(bumper),
        $startPos = $from.offset().top + $from.height(),
        bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
        setPosition = function(){
            if ($window.scrollTop() < $startPos) { 
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: $startPos
                });
            } else if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        };
    $window.resize(function()
    {
        bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};

$('#two').followTo('#one', '#footer');
```

Comment: The javascript console displays the following error when I resize my window  on your JSFiddle: `Uncaught ReferenceError: pos is not defined` - this refers to `bumperPos = pos.offset().top;` - where does `pos` come from?

Comment: Don't know the answer to that. This is copied code from here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/10434/

Comment: Thanks for your response Polyov. Help is very welcome if you can?

Comment: normally it's spelled "window", not "windw".

Comment: and that is the problem, tested out the jsfiddle with the correct spelling, it worked.

Comment: this is like an "oh god, I can't believe i missed that" moment.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fLyrg57t/18/  Thanks. This with the spelling corrected but still the same problem. Or have I missed one?

Comment: Thanks. I think I know what's causing the problem. Please see the update on the original question. Perhaps you can help?

Comment: Hey. I couldn't see your comment before as I'm working on some tight deadlines. In any case, I've just had the chance to take a look at your code, see if my updated version helps: https://jsfiddle.net/fLyrg57t/25/ I'll write an answer explaining the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've made three modifications:

- The `pos` variable was not defined, it should be `bumper`.
- Reset `$startPos` on resize—this fixes the problem of element(s) above the sticky element changing their height/position on resize.
- Moved the fixed element's `top` value to a parameter in the `followTo` function, and take it in consideration when switching the `fixed`/`absolute` positions for a smoother transition.

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLyrg57t/27/).

```
$.fn.followTo = function (from, bumper, fixedOffsetTop) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(window),
        $from = $(from),
        $bumper = $(bumper),
        $startPos = $from.offset().top + $from.height(),
        bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
        setPosition = function(){
            if ($window.scrollTop() < $startPos - fixedOffsetTop) { 
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: $startPos
                });
            } else if ($window.scrollTop() > bumperPos - thisHeight - fixedOffsetTop) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: fixedOffsetTop
                });
            }
        };
    $window.resize(function()
    {
        $startPos = $from.offset().top + $from.height();
        bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};

$('#two').followTo('#one', '#footer', 30);
```