# Div only fixed between two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the following code ([**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/)). But is there a way to not have the fixed div scroll between a to points set in pixels from the top, but between two divs above and below the Fixed div?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#theFixed").css("top",Math.max(0,250-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

Comment: What have you  tried?

Comment: It's all math, bro. Your code says 250px minus the value of ScrollTop of the window object. If you want to calculate the height of two divs and use that for the `top` CSS property, you totally can.

Comment: all sort of different approaches in code but none seem to work:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492032/divs-fixed-and-unfixed-toggle-between-two-absolute-divs

Comment: @ Matthew. Thanks. Let me put together a JSFiddle. Then perhaps you are willing to add your solution?

Comment: I need the theFixed div to scroll (be fixed) between marker and footer. On the marker it works. How can I make it work on the footer also, so the theFixed div not go over footer also. Updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/3418/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to really understand your question but as long as you modify

```
Math.max(0,250-$(this).scrollTop())
```

There should be no specification. Like `(20,250...)` for 20 px from top.

And if you want to specify a div you can use `$('thediv').offset()`

Like this :

```
var offset = $("#theFixed").offset()
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#theFixed").css("top",Math.max(offset.top,250-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

Live exemple  [there](http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/3411/)

Comment: thanks! I have made an update to your example. I need the theFixed div to scroll (be fixed) between marker and footer. On the marker it works. How can I make it work on the footer also, so the theFixed div not go over footer also. Updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/3418/